# Nested Template Issue C++

Tags: c++

I have a templated node class declared as

```
    template <class T_>
    class Node : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T_, T_>
    {
    ...
    }
```

Which works fine, and I'm trying to take this existing class and apply it to a new linked list class.

I'd like to create it by calling something along the lines of

```
    LinkedList<float> nodeList;
```

where it implicitly takes the type given, and within the structure of the class handles it as Node of type T_.

Is there a way to do this without making the node a sub-class of LinkedList?

Comment: Apart of a main question, do you think it is a good idea to inherit `Node` from `std::iterator`? I don't see an "is a" relationship here. Probably you must rethink your class design.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are asking?

```
template <class T_>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    typedef Node<T_> node_type;

    void AddNode(node_type *node)
    { /*...*/ }
};
```

Technically, the `typedef` is not necessary, but IME it is a good pratice to typedef the dependent types in this way.

Comment: In the end result, the main program won't know about nodes directly, just their behavior.  So I've tried something along the lines of void AddNode(T_ value){ /*...*/ } and it gives me a strange error
cannot convert from 'Node<T_> *' to 'Node<T_> *'.  Never seen that with the same type, lol... does that mean there's an issue with my copy ctor?

Comment: @Kiery as you've got 3 answers and all of them about different things, I think that you need to edit your question explaining what you want to achieve more precisely, and add relevant code to get meaningful answers.

Comment: @Drop, that's fair enough.  I'm just trying to re-evaluate what I'm trying to do at this point, the problem may sort itself but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Kiery: If you have a weird error like that, you should post a minimal code that shows it, and we will look at it. Probable there is a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correct, you need to instantiate a class template using templated class type. Use this syntax:

```
LinkedList<Node<float> > nodeList;
```

<sub>(notice a space between `> >`; it is always a good idea to add it, because old versions of some compilers have troubles on distinguishing such constructs from shift operators `>>`)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, sadly the main will not be directly aware of nodes and thus can only be typed as LinkedList<float>

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the iterator as a default template argument:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Iterator = Node<T>
> class LinkedList
{
    // ...
};
```